# Class Zip Archive not found using PhpSpreadsheet (Mac)

Tags: php, xampp, phpoffice

I'm using the latest XAMPP, and I've downloaded PhpSpreadsheet with composer, but upon requesting the file, it says that Class 'ZipArchive' is not found.
This is my code so far:

```
$file = './data/data.xlsx';
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($file);
```

I've already tried installing php through brew again, still doesn't work. 
However, typing -m in the terminal does show the zip module. 
Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

---

Edit: it appears that there's no Zip in `phpinfo()` either

Comment: The web server config and the command line config are often different. Run `phpinfo()` from a web page to see what modules are installed and which `php.ini` file is being used.

Comment: oh ok, just tried it and there's no Zip in `phpinfo()`. Is there any way to activate it?